# Change order confirmation email text

Tags: email, order-email

On the generic order confirmation emails that are sent out after a customer places and order, how do I go in and changed the email address for customers with questions to contact us? Right now it's support@example.com. This needs to change.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **System > Transactional Emails** and add a new template based on the "New Order email". You may need to do this for registered customers and guests. You can change the email text in the new template. Then choose the new template for use in **System > Config > Sales Emails**

If you can't see `support@example.com` in the "New Order email" and can only see something like `{{var store_email}}` then check **System > Config > General > Store Email Addresses** to make sure you have set that up correctly.